# Get rid of extra space

Tags: html, css

Have following codes in php file: from code the first line defines title (first line from screenshot), second one city, third and fourth ones defines 'price_new' or 'price' next to the city if exists (second line from screenshot), five and six ones define price_two and min_amount (third line from screenshot) and the last one is category (fourth line from screenshot):

The problem is I can't get rid off extra space between second and third lines from screenshot:

```
<a class="b" title="<?=$last['title']?>" href="<?="c".$last['id_category']."-".$last['board_id']?>.html"><?=$last['title']?></a><br /><span>

      <? if(defined('JBLANG')&& constant('JBLANG')=='en') echo $last['en_city_name']; else echo $last['city_name'];
         if(($last['price'] > $last['price_new']) && ($last['price_new'] != 0)) echo " | <s class=\"red\">".$last['price']." ".$last['prise']."</s>.";
         if($last['price'] != 0 && $last['price_new'] == 0) echo " | <span class=\"green\">".$last['price']." ".$last['prise']."</span>";  
         if ($last["price_two"]) echo '</span><br /><a style="display: inline-block;" class="sm_11"><span>Цена Оптом</span> <span class="green">'.$last["price_two"].' '.$last["price_two_currency"].'<span></a>';
         if ($last["min_amount"]) echo ' | <a style="display: inline-block;" class="sm_11" style="margin-left: 22%;"><span>Мин. кол-во</span> <span class="green">'.$last["min_amount"].' '.$last["min_amount_currency"].'<span></a>' ?>

         </span>
         <br /><a style="display: inline-block;" class="sm_11" title="<?=$last[$name_cat]?>" href="<?="c".$last['id_category']?>.html"><?=$last[$name_cat]?></a>
```

Thanks,
S

[image]

Comment: use css line-height or margin

Comment: (1) tidy up and correct your html, you have some unpaired `<span>` tags. And for followup questions (2) post relevant CSS for `.sm_11` class

Comment: @PA. I'm not good at html, can you put correct code with removed unpaired <span> tags? thanks

Comment: You just need to tidy up your code, the unmatched tags will appear clearly.

First, grab a good ibook on html and php to get started!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a class to the div/html tag you're using. Here's an example:

```css
.example_class{
  line-height:1px;
}

.large_example_class{
  line-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example_class">
   <p> Hello </p>
   <p> World </p>
</div>

<div class="large_example_class">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Line height does however affect the whitespace both above and under the text lines in the div. If you want to do it individually you need to do it like this:

```css
.line_1{
  margin: 0px;
}

.line_2{
  margin-top:10px;
}

.line_3{
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="line_1">Hello</p>
  <p class="line_2">World</p>
  <p class="line_3">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Basically here you set the margin on the top, which only affects the given line. If you however reuse this class with other itme they'll be affected in the same way.

In your example I'd use the following:

```html
<?php 
  echo'</span><p><a style="display:block; background-color:white;">Hello</a></p>'
```

However, you should change your style attribute with a class to make it more universal. If you wish to know more about this code look at websites like [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) or [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/index.htm)

Comment: thanks for the answer!! can you try to apply what you mentioned(add a class to the div/html tag) to my example, sorry but I'm not familiar with html codes? Thanks Satyric Abyss!!

Comment: what confuses in my case, if and echo are used so not sure how to apply the solution with adding a class to the div/html tag: if($last['price'] != 0 && $last['price_new'] == 0)  echo '</span><br /><a style="display: inline-block;"

Comment: Right so where you open a tag, e.g. <div> or <span>, it doesn't matter what it is, you just simply add <div class="your_class"> or <span class="your_class">. Then you can put that in your style sheet.

Your stylesheet can be added by creating a new .css file, like "stylesheet.css", and add it to your project in the parts:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link src="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
YOUR HTML / PHP HERE
</body>

Comment: Maybe it's useful for you to read through the basics of HTML to avoid further issues. W3 schools is a good place to start!

Comment: Thanks!! what about <br /> , do I need to use it, it starts new line? in your example above you didn't use it but lines still breaks into two.

Comment: Yea a <p> is a cleaner way to use breaklines. It's also a lot more universal when it comes to classes, styling, etc. A <br/> is just a breakline.

Comment: what about if, I believe I should put it out of  <p> Hello </p>  and should I put "echo '</span><br /><a style="display: inline-block;" class="sm_11">" inside <p>  </p>? thanks!!

Comment: If you want to echo it in php, you should put it like `echo </span><p><a style="yourstyle"></p>`.